# get_template_part() based on get_post_type() for a custom post type instead of get_post_format()

Tags: get-template-part

I have custom post type of `portfolio` and I would like to be able to re-use most of the templating, but change to `content-portfolio` when the page is a custom post type named `portfolio`.

At present this is not working, so I'm not sure if I need to add Custom Post Types in the Main Query or add it inside the while loop?

**index.php CODE:**

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header>
                <?php if( single_post_title( '', false ) ) : ?>
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <h1 class="page-title">
                        <?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                    </h1>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </header>


        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
              if(get_post_type()) : {
                      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
                  elseif :
                      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                endif;
            }
                ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I see my error. I mean it's not working.

Comment: This is the part I was hoping would work based on the type. But I'm not sure it's working inside the while loop, or I've not referenced the custom post type.

[code]    <?php
              if(get_post_type()) : {
                      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
                  elseif :
                      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                endif;
            }
                ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Make sure you are using the correct template file:

First, you need to make sure `index.php` is being used as the template. You may install [What The File Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/), which will show what template file is being used at the top bar when you're logged in.

### Set the proper condition for `portfolio`:

Once you are sure that `index.php` is used as the template and ***you have `template-parts/content-portfolio` file within your active theme***, then you may use the following CODE for the `get_post_type()` check to determine which template-part should be used:

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php
        if( get_post_type() === 'portfolio' ) :
              get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
        else :
              get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
        endif;
    ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

### Update: CODE swap based on comment:

Replace:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_format( array( 'gallery', 'video', 'image' ) ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    }
    else { 
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
    }
?>
```

with:

```
<?php
    if( get_post_type() === 'portfolio' ) {
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
    }
    else if ( has_post_format( array( 'gallery', 'video', 'image' ) ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    }
    else { 
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Fayaz, but it didn't work. I've installed  [https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/](What The File Plugin), very useful!. However when I'm on the portfolio single page (details) it's using the template-parts/content-single.php. I can just use single-portfolio.php which does work but I was hoping or my understanding that I can re-use using the get_template_part call just divert it to template-parts/content-portfolio.php. The main /portfolio page which is diaplaying a loop grid of the custom post types is using page.php [template-parts/content-page.php].

Comment: So I just found the portfolio-single page is using single.php with a `   <?php if ( has_post_format( array( 'gallery', 'video', 'image' ) ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
   } else {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
   } ?>`

I not sure how to re-write that as an elseif?

Comment: So replacing the original `if, else` in single.php with the above code answer the single portfolio page is picking up the `template-parts/content-portfolio.php`. I just need some help with the logic to mix the original `if, else  to include the `get_post_type() === 'portfolio'`

Comment: okay, scrap that. I just realised my code does do a get_post_format() check. So the above worked I just had it in the wrong file. [wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/] (What The File Plugin) really helped here! Thanks Fayaz

Answer (score 1):

So I'm using [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) with template-parts\content-___.php to be able re-use parts of my template structure. I was using a custom post type `portfolio` and I wanted my template to automatically pick up the `-portfolio.php` rather than use single-portfolio.php. Using the What The File Plugin I finally realised it was using `single.php` file with the `template-part\content-single.php`. The logic needed changing inside the file `single.php` which originally was:

```
<?php 
  if ( has_post_format( array( 'gallery', 'video', 'image' ) ) ) {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
  } else {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
  } 
?>
```

and changed this to:

```
<?php 
  if( get_post_type() === 'portfolio' ) :
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
  else :
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );               
  endif;
?>
```